# Change next_post and previous_link to navigate throught parent categories only

Tags: categories, permalinks, next-post-link, previous-post-link

I have this unchanged code from template-tags.php which links through all of the posts on the site. However I would like to restrict it so that it only links through the articles which are in the same parent category.

```
<nav role="navigation" id="<?php echo $nav_id; ?>" class="<?php echo $nav_class; ?>">
        <h1 class="assistive-text"><?php _e( 'Post navigation', 'IQ' ); ?></h1>

    <?php if ( is_single() ) : // navigation links for single posts ?>

        <?php previous_post_link( '<div class="nav-previous">%link</div>', '<span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '&larr;', 'Previous post link', 'IQ' ) . '</span> %title' ); ?>
        <?php next_post_link( '<div class="nav-next">%link</div>', '%title <span class="meta-nav">' . _x( '&rarr;', 'Next post link', 'IQ' ) . '</span>' ); ?>

    <?php elseif ( $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 && ( is_home() || is_archive() || is_search() ) ) : // navigation links for home, archive, and search pages ?>

        <?php if ( get_next_posts_link() ) : ?>
        <div class="nav-previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( '<span class="meta-nav">&larr;</span> Older posts', 'IQ' ) ); ?></div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ( get_previous_posts_link() ) : ?>
        <div class="nav-next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'IQ' ) ); ?></div>
        <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endif; ?>

    </nav><!-- #<?php echo $nav_id; ?> -->
```

The site works like a magazine site, so we have a new issue every few months. The new issue is a new parent category, with new child categories to hold the respective articles. If someone is in Issue 0 -> News i would like them to be able to scroll through all of the articles in Issue 0 from that article.

Does anyone know how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass a third argument `true` to both `previous/next_post_link()` ([see codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/next_post_link))